# MySQL: How to update foreign key field, and create a relationship, after table values have been set with default values?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a teamnews Table: [image]

And another table called team:
[image]

The values in teamnews table are predetermined before a user signs into the site.
Lets say when a user(`teamName`) signs in I want to update the `teamID` row where `NewsID` = 1 
And create a relationship so that if I eventually delete the user(`teamName`) the `teamID` value in the teamNews table is reset to zero.

Is this possible?
Please bare in mind I am using phpMyAdmin, so I am not entirely familiar with advanced SQL terms.

When I try to do this I get and error: [image]

Here's the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). You can add it in by running this command:

```
ALTER TABLE teamnews
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_teamID
  FOREIGN KEY (TeamID)
  REFERENCES team (teamID)
  ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

This sets up a formal relationship between the tables using the foreign key. The `ON DELETE SET NULL` is the part that is important to you. This says that whenever any item in the referenced table (`team` in this instance) is deleted, then all rows in this table that had that team id should set that field to null — exactly what you're looking for.

Be aware that this will only work if you are using the `InnoDB` database engine (not the `MyISAM` engine). You can probably change that through phpmyadmin somewhere (I'm not familiar with phpmyadmin so I can't help you on the details).

Also be aware that for this to work, MySQL must actually be able to "SET NULL" -- the field containing the foreign key with this constraint can't be set to "NOT NULL" or it will fail with an error saying to "check data type".

Comment: I think the problem is that your `teamID` field in the `teamnews` table is set to "NOT NULL". Please update it to allow null values (and set the default value to `NULL` instead of `0`). Then try adding the foreign key again.